# Error when committing property changes to the trunk of my SVN repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I've made a change to the properties of the trunk of my repository. Specifically I have modified an extern to point to a newer version.

When I commit I get the following error.

```
Commit failed (details follow):
Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:
error: you don't have enough permissions for this transaction:
you can't update properties of trunk/
```

Comment: So are you able to commit to the trunk a file or new directory? The error message here is clear (in my opinion). Perhaps there is a pre-commit hook (living on the server), that hinders you in committing the  change. Get in touch with your SVN admin, and ask him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out the problem.

The change is to the \conf\svnperms.conf file located within the root of the repository. This file looks like this:

```
[_default_]
trunk/.*          = *(add,remove,update)
branches/[^/]+/.* = *(add,remove,update)
tags/[^/]+/       = *(add,remove)
trunk/            = *(add)
branches/         = *(add)
tags/             = *(add)
```

I made the modification shown below.

```
trunk/            = *(add)
```

to

```
trunk/            = *(add,update)
```